# Angular2 Forms: Getting "Object" at console as result of input field element.value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

Im trying to print content of input field in the form of angular2 but getting object at the console as result (myform type of ControlGroup), here is my code look like, why this happens actually

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, ControlGroup, AbstractControl, 
FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';


@Component({
  selector : 'formbuilder',
  template : `
    <h1> FOrm Using Formbuilder </h1>
    <form  [ngFormModel] = "myform" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit(myform.value)">
      <lable>Name: </lable>
      <input type = "text" [ngFormControl] = "myform.controls['input1']" />
      <input type = "text" [ngFormControl] = "myform.controls['input2']" />
      <button type = "text">Submit</button>  
    </form>
  `,
  directives : [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class formbuilder {
  myform : ControlGroup ;
  ac : AbstractControl;
  constructor(fb : FormBuilder) {
    this.myform = fb.group({
      'input1' : ['ABC', Validators.required],
      'input2' : ['DEF', Validators.required]
    }); 
    this.ac = this.myform.controls['ac']
  }

  onSubmit(value : any) : void {
    console.log("submit method called "  + value);
  }
}
bootstrap(formbuilder);
```

Comment: Why do you think `myform.value` will give you the value of a text field? You're literally asking for the value of the entire form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tested your code and `myForm.value` contains the following:

```
{input1: "ABC", input2: "DEF"}
```

This corresponds to the value of all controls you defined.

If you want to input of a particular field you can use this:

```
this.myform.controls.input1.value;
```

Comment: yes, but why it has to happen object written on console

Comment: If you only put `console.log(value);`, you will be able to introspect the object in the console and that it only has properties `input1` and `input2`...

Comment: You can also use `console.log(JSON.stringify(value));`

Comment: You have always been amazing to me!